# Weird auto layout issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Based on previous question, I learnt Autolayout carefully. In practice project, everything perform normal in viewController. But it really not work in my own tableView cell. The weird thing continued, and I feel so desperate.

[I have a tableviewcell with two labels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AiaM.png)

[All the constraints were settled, xcode reads blue lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmG3t.png)

[Blue lines shown normal in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WS4P.png)

But once I ran the program, the label crowded together at x = 0, y = 0 to content view.[This is so weired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I3Ud.png)

[This is the label attribute settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4NHz.png)

[This is tableview cell settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtt2N.png)
[This is tableview cell setting too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9nkh.png)

This is the code for height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
    return 100
    } else {
    return 40
    }
}
```

For all above, I set x, y, height, width, there should nothing left. But it really not work. I have got into this trouble for days. How could I fix this well?

UPDATE:

I added one more constraint on "this is a label" label: leading space to 1st label. Also I also down sized the 2nd label's content hugging and compression priority, so that the constant word should be fully shown. [Added constraint and modified priority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVaxr.png)

I cannot upload more than 8 links, so its a pity that I cannot upload a updated picture.

But this two labels still merged. Dose there anything else I still missing?

UPDATE2:

I solved this through deleted the tableViewController, and rebuilt a new one. It worked but I really don't know what happened in the old one.

Comment: If you have to constraint label width or height, you are doing it wrong, It should be pining 4 side of the label to the cell/other subview, for 2 label next to each other, change their content hugging/compression resistance priority instead of width constraint

Comment: Could I ask what "pining 4 side of the label to the cell/other subview" really means? For example, the left label, I tried to show a constant word. So I set height, width, leading space to content view, and vertically in content view. Did you mean this is wrong?

Comment: You have 2 labels "title label" and "this is a label". In this 2nd label's leading constraint should be pinned to the 1st label's trailing constraint.

Comment: From your screenshot, i can see that 2nd Label's trailing is pinned with superview's trailing. You also need to add 1 more constraint which is pinning 2nd label's leading with 1st label's trailing.

Comment: Also you need to set content hugging / compression resistance priority to make sure that both labels don't merge with each other.

Comment: I added one more constraint on "this is a label" label: leading space to 1st label. Also I also down sized the 2nd label's content hugging and compression priority, so that the constant word should be fully shown. But they still merged. Could you please tell me if anything else I still missing? This confusing me so much.